# C# how to parse dynamic value of "MyValue"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to parse dynamic value of MyValue :

MyValue has value like-> ValueKind = Number : "0"

The code is:

```
var pdfAttributeModelDataSet = JsonAttributeHealth.Select(x => new 
        {
            ResponsibilityInfo = x.PersianName,
            //YearlyResponsibility="",
            MyValue = x.Value,
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `JsonAttributeHealth`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman it's a just name.
`
`var JsonAttributeHealth = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProductAttributeModel>>(order.JsonAttributeValue!);`

Answer (score 2):

you can use

> Convert.ToString

for your purpose and give the number of your string

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's better to use javaScriptSerializer to serialize and de-serialize your data.

```
public class Class1
{

    public Class1()
    {        
   
      var param = user.PersianName + "," + user.Value;
      var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(param, stringBuilder);
      ...
    }
}

internal class user
{
    public static string PersianName {get; internal set;}
    public static string Value {get; internal set;}
}
```